# C# appdomain permission no thread

Tags: c#, security, permissions, appdomain, appdomainsetup

I create appdomains to dynamically load dll's to - as supposed.

However I did not manage to stop an unhandled exception from terminating the whole thing - as it seems is not possible.

However I really would not have to if I just could forbid the creation of new Threads in the 3rd party dll.

Is there a way to forbid thread creation (and maybe task creation) in an custom AppDomain and if yes: How?

P.S.: I already learned about System.AddIn. I will take a look at it if no one has a positive answer.

Comment: I'm not aware that this is possible, but even if it were, doing so would prevent the 3rd-party dll from working the way it was designed, rendering it useless at best and causing crashes at worst.

Comment: @MattDavis So why is this? The loaded classes are supposed to answer to framework calls. Threads a per application and not per AppDomain, are they?

Comment: Technically, the execution of an application occurs within an AppDomain, but an application is free to launch multiple AppDomains.  I know this to be true from personal experience.  As I understand your question, you've got a .NET-based assembly (dll) that you do not own, but it is launching a thread that is ultimately crashing your application.  If you were to preclude the thread from running (assuming this is even possible, and again, I don't think it is), almost certainly that assembly will not work as expected.  Better off to catch the exception and deal with it somehow.

Comment: Thank you Matt. The Assembly is 3rd Party but it uses a dll from us to build. I only pass control flow to classes which inherited from an interface I provide.  All Framework calls are nested in try catch. Opening a new thread would be a clear misuse of our Framework. If within the "unwanted" thread an unhandled exception is thrown there is nothing I can do.